# Get maximum value and most recent from a column - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has the following structure:

```
id     blood_pressure    created
```

So for every id, I want to get the : highest blood_pressure (max(blood_pressure), as well as the latest blood_pressure created, in one query.
I need:

```
 id     max(blood_pressure). latest(blood_pressure value)
```

How can I write this query in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: @PM77-1 Not sure I follow. Max of blood pressure, si the highest value for it. And then I also need the value of the most recent blood pressure. What do you mean for both fields?

Comment: I misunderstood your requirements.  I though you needed latest date.

Comment: There could be a Primary Key for this table. Is it `(id,created)` ?

Comment: @wildplasser no, the table has a lot more columns. I just simplified it. 
There is another id/uuid column that is the key.

Comment: @PM77-1 Apologies if my ask was not clear.

Comment: The best way to simplify a table is by specifying its PK. The rest of the columns are just dependant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *window functions* to find the max per group and latest per group, such as:

```
with p as (
    select *,
      Max(pressure) over(partition by Id) HighestPressure,
      Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by Created desc) rn
    from t
)
select Id, Pressure, HighestPressure
from p
where rn=1;
```

*Untested of course with no sample data to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` to get the latest pressure, and the `max` window function to get the highest:

```
select distinct on(id) id,
max(blood_pressure) over(partition by id) as max_pressure,
blood_pressure as latest_pressure
from table_name
order by id, created desc;
```